# Fetch header data using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to fetch image and save in memory cache in glide, and update the cache only if last updated header is changed in URL using SIGNATURES.

How to fetch headers data of the image URL, to get last updated time.

This is the header I receive in URL:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK => 
Content-Type => image/jpeg
Content-Length => 15796
Connection => close
Date => Tue, 05 Jun 2018 11:50:21 GMT
Last-Modified => Sun, 13 May 2018 10:38:09 GMT
ETag => "6423f90cca1fa813a78b1307c7470bf3"
x-amz-version-id => SSQ.meXMNsROn9tRB_uA8E1ik75Ov1St
Accept-Ranges => bytes
Server => AmazonS3
X-Cache => Miss from cloudfront
Via => 1.1 aa4d149b02744d3034b526d8099be7c0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id => PghnT-Tgh3R7qeD19t6_QfBcq1Ibf8cwTsU9JoWxNK_xMEiGzDl6Mg==
```

How to fetch this header in glide to update signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
.apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
```

like ..

```
 Glide.with(context).load(CommonUtils.checkForNullValue(userData.getUserVo().getPhoto())).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
                .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.big_user))
                .into(holder.ivUserImage);
```

Comment: This doesn't update the image when a new image is uploaded in same url